# Simultaneous recording video (back and front camera) at the same time and save into one file

Tags: android, android-camera2, android-mediacodec

I'm trying make simultaneous recording video (back and front camera) at the same time. Front camera is full screen and near camera on the left. I'm using camera2 API to open 2 camera simultaneous and record, the record video will save into 2 .mp4 files.
Now, I want output is 1 .mp4 file (front video is full and back video in the left).

I did researched, I can do it by use MediaMuxer to combine 2 camera resource into once and save it into a file. so how I can arrange near video on the left?

So, anyone have any suggestion to do it? and any suggestion to do simultaneous recording video (near and front camera) at the same time and save into one file

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

`MediaMuxer` only combines multiple tracks into one container file. It doesn't do video compositing.

A high level overview of a possible solution:

You can feed the frames from the 2 camera devices into `SurfaceTexture` objects. This makes them available as OpenGL ES external textures. Next you can combine the frames into a single image using OpenGL ES. Finally, you can encode the output of OpenGL ES using the `MediaCodec` API and write it to a file using the `MediaMuxer`.

Some documentation to get started: [1](https://developer.android.com/develop/ui/views/graphics/opengl), [2](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaCodec), [3](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaMuxer)